# I need help with installation of ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive

I need help with installtion of ubuntu, let me clear it so i decided to switch to ubuntu from windows few days ago and setup everything and tried ubuntu but when i was installing it disk partion part came i checked it but it's hard to recognize them as even in MB it's not similar as we see in windows like I have to install ubuntu replacing windows in C drive of 68 GB but as it's not windows os i can't see the name nor the exact storage in MB i revert all process becuase the data in other drives are important to me so can you explain how to see exact same storgae or any hint to know the disk? Also one more thing let me clear you is I have replaced drive 1 with pendrive to boot and I have 2 hard disk each of 190GB please help

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The main thing I'd like to know before trying to help is - are you looking to replace Windows with Ubuntu completely, ie delete all of Windows and its data, and set the computer up with Ubuntu only? If so, back anything up that you want to keep (which you must do anyway before installing OS or doing anything so invasive) and we can talk you through a fresh installation including wiping the drive completely. If you want to keep your Windows installation and set up dual boot it's more complicated.

Comment: Hey @Will , I need to fresh install but my hard drive contains some important data and i can't just backup or store in cloud as it's over 100 GB that's why i am confused..

Comment: No @matigo, i just need to know how to fresh install ubuntu as no windows data is important to me but data on other drives is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install ubuntu in a specific partition or drive, things can get a little confusing. I found [these instructions on LinuxTechi.com](https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-20-04-lts-installation-steps-screenshots/) (not affiliated, just found them searching) When you select *Something else* on *Installation type* dialog, then you can see the different drives more clearly.

Another tip that might help you is that drive names actually follow a pattern:

> - The first floppy drive is named /dev/fd0.
> - The second floppy drive is named /dev/fd1.
> - The first hard disk detected is named /dev/sda.
> - The second hard disk detected is named /dev/sdb, and so on.
> - The first SCSI CD-ROM is named /dev/scd0, also known as /dev/sr0.

(See Ubuntu help, [Device Names in Linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apcs04.html))

Also you can judge the size if you see them in different units by their magnitude. Generally speaking KB is x1024 Bytes, MB is x1024 KBs and GB is x1024 MBs and so on.

```
Kilobyte KB   1024 Bytes              1,024
Megabyte MB   1024 Kilobytes      1,048,576
Gigabyte GB   1024 Megabytes  1,073,741,824
```

(See [Understanding file sizes from GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-file-sizes-bytes-kb-mb-gb-tb-pb-eb-zb-yb/))

I hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with it

Comment: @Aestra no worries. we've all been there so many times.

Comment: can we talk in discord i have few more queries related to same problem...